# Найти группы с меньшим или равным количеством студентов, PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть таблица(students), где каждый студент(всего 200) распределен в одну из 10 групп(group_id). Нужно написать запрос на postgresSQL, который сможет найти группы с наименьшем или равным количеством студентов. Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

```
WITH
  group_data AS (SELECT group_id, count(*) AS count FROM student GROUP BY group_id)
SELECT
  *
FROM
  group_data
WHERE
  count = (SELECT MIN(count) FROM group_data);
```

Comment: почему бы не использовать HAVING?